# Supressing null values in export to Excel in QlikView

Tags: excel, qlikview

I load the values in a QlikView dropdown through an Excel sheet.

Example data:

```
head    subhead   amount
-------------------------
abc     abc1
def     def1
```

`abc` and `def` are in the `head` dropdown, and `abc1` and `def1` are in `subhead` dropdown.

There is also a text box for input by the user which contains the value amount to assign.

When I select `head` `abc` against `subhead` `abc1`, I enter a value, say, `100` in the textbox, then when I click on add, data is added in table.

However, when I export this table into an Excel sheet, data is displayed like this

```
head    subhead   amount
-------------------------
abc     abc1 
def     def1
abc     abc1      100
```

This means that all values which I load from Excel in the first place, is also exported in Excel sheet. How do I export only this:

```
head    subhead   amount
-------------------------
abc     abc1      100
```

I also tried "suppress value is null" but this did not work.

**Update**

Second table is table box, and first is straight table so I want to hide these "-" values data, and when I export "-" values must not be exported to Excel.

[image]

Comment: what is the expression?

Comment: @EldadT expression for what

Comment: on table there is not any expression

Comment: chekck updated please

Comment: if you want to export from table box make sure you choose the "omit empty values" for the month field in the presentation tab ...